# Как убрать значение label в input type radio?

Tags: html, css, input, label, radiobutton

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать при помощи css, чтобы "100" не отображалось.

```html
<li>
  <label for="id_star_cena_0">
    <input type="radio" name="star_cena" value="5" class="rating-star" required id="id_star_cena_0">

    100

    </label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
li label[for="id_star_cena_0"] {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```

```html
<li>
  <label for="id_star_cena_0">
    <input type="radio" name="star_cena" value="5" class="rating-star" required id="id_star_cena_0">

    100

    </label>
</li>
```

Comment: Зато при выделении видно xD

Answer (score 1):

```css
.id_star_cena_0 {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <label for="id_star_cena_0" class="id_star_cena_0">
    <input type="radio" name="star_cena" value="5" class="rating-star" required id="id_star_cena_0">

    100

    </label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.add-rating label {
font-size: 0px;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]